# Recoding missing data in longitudinal data frames with R

Tags: r, missing-data, panel-data

I have a data frame with a similar longitudinal structure as `data`:

```
data = data.frame (
   ID = c("a","a","a","b","b","b","c","c", "c"), 
   period = c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3),
   size = c(3,3,NA, NA, NA,1, 14,14, 14))
```

The values of the variable `size` are fixed so that each period has the same value for `size`. Yet some observations have missing values. My aim consists of replacing these missing values
with the value of `size` associated with the periods where there is no missing (e.g. 3 for `ID` "a" and 1 for `ID` "b").

The desired data frame should look something similar to:

```
data.1 

    ID period value
      a      1     3
      a      2     3
      a      3     3
      b      1     1
      b      2     1
      b      3     1
      c      1    14
      c      2    14
      c      3    14
```

I have tried different combinations of the formula below but I don't get the result I am looking for.

```
library(dplyr)

data.1 = data %>% group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(new.size = ifelse(is.na(size), !is.na(size),
                          ifelse(!is.na(size), size, 0)))
```

That yields the following:

```
data.1
Source: local data frame [9 x 4]
Groups: ID [3]

      ID period  size new.size
  (fctr)  (dbl) (dbl)    (dbl)
1      a      1     3        3
2      a      2     3        3
3      a      3    NA        0
4      b      1    NA        0
5      b      2    NA        0
6      b      3     1        1
7      c      1    14       14
8      c      2    14       14
9      c      3    14       14
```

I would be grateful if someone could give me a hint on how to get the right solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here another solution using `dplyr` with `na.omit`

```
group_by(data, ID) %>%
     mutate(value=na.omit(size)[1])
Source: local data frame [9 x 4]
Groups: ID [3]

      ID period  size value
  <fctr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1      a      1     3     3
2      a      2     3     3
3      a      3    NA     3
4      b      1    NA     1
5      b      2    NA     1
6      b      3     1     1
7      c      1    14    14
8      c      2    14    14
9      c      3    14    14
```

note that you can replace `na.omit` with  `max(size, na.rm=TRUE)` if you are looking for maximum for example.

Answer (score 3):

How about this with base R:

```
vals <- unique(na.omit(data[, c("ID", "size")]))
data$size <- vals$size[match(data$ID, vals$ID)]


  ID period size
1  a      1    3
2  a      2    3
3  a      3    3
4  b      1    1
5  b      2    1
6  b      3    1
7  c      1   14
8  c      2   14
9  c      3   14
```

Comment: You can also do with `dplyr` i.e. `data %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(new.size = size[!is.na(size)][1])`

Answer (score 3):

To correct your code, you can try the following with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% group_by(ID) %>% 
         mutate(new.size = ifelse(is.na(size), size[!is.na(size)],size))

#      ID   period  size new.size
#     (fctr)  (dbl) (dbl)    (dbl)
#1      a      1     3        3
#2      a      2     3        3
#3      a      3    NA        3
#4      b      1    NA        1
#5      b      2    NA        1
#6      b      3     1        1
#7      c      1    14       14
#8      c      2    14       14
#9      c      3    14       14
```

---

Or a `base R` alternative with `ave`

```
data$new.size <- ave(data$size,data$ID, FUN=function(x)unique(x[!is.na(x)]))
data$new.size

#[1]  3  3  3  1  1  1 14 14 14
```